# SQL single query loop

Tags: sql

I'm being asked to answer the following question. Can someone help me with this?
And for you experts out there, on a scale of 1-10, how difficult is this?

A marketing company had 3 different kinds of policy. Its database has a Customer table with (Cust_ID ,Policy_ID) where CUST_id uniquely identifies each customer and the Policy_ID identifies one of the three policy they hold.

Write a single query that will return the number of customers holding each kind of policy.

Comment: This is a 1, provide your table structure, some sample data, and the desired results (in a data format)

Comment: Learn how to ask question!!!  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this would be a simple aggregate query.

sample data

```
declare @Customer table
(   Customer_ID int
    ,Policy_ID int
)

insert into @Customer
(Customer_ID, Policy_ID)
values
(1, 1),
(2,1),
(3,2),
(4,2),
(5,2),
(6,3),
(7,3),
(8,3),
(9,3)
```

Query:

```
select Policy_ID, count(*) from @Customer group by Policy_ID
```

Results:

```
Policy_ID   count
1           2
2           3
3           4
```

Comment: From the way that I read it, OP wanted the 3 policies, with the number of customers for each. That would require grouping by `Policy_ID`.

Comment: Your answer is ok - sorry for my to fast reading and writing

Comment: No worries! I was afraid I had missed something obvious in his post. :)

Answer (score -2):

this is simplest possible task
it is something like

```
SELECT Policy_ID, COUNT(*)
FROM
Customer 
GROUP BY Policy_ID
```

then if you define 1 as simplest and 10 as hardest
then this is 1

Comment: Thanks, I'm use to using Laravel Eloquent when querying a DB. I haven't used raw sql syntax in awhile.

Comment: Then this answer is a 0 since it’s incorrect.

Comment: @ Joakim Danielson to fast copy paste, fixed now

Comment: "this is simplest possible task".  And your query doesn't even run.  What does that tell you???

Comment: That i ignore this question and not spent enought time on it ;-) funny above answer by @Zack have the same error ^^

Comment: @Livius His query runs fine.  Wrong, but it runs.  Yours wrong and doesn't run.

Comment: @Livius Actually his query is right, because OP asked for the number of customer for each policy.

Comment: Yes Group by POLICY_ID is good one - sometimes simple questions cause the most errors

Comment: @Livius Not if you test your own code...